# How to load a themes folder in rollup, similar to how sass-resources-loader in webpack

Tags: sass, rollupjs

I had a themes folder which, when using webpack, I was able to use sass-resources-loader to load a specific theme file. And all references to variables defined there would be seen throughout my other scss files.

I've tried using rollup-plugin-sass, rollup-plugin-scss, using postcss-theme with rollup-plugin-postcss. I'm stumped. I feel there's a simple solution to this which I'm not seeing...

sass-resources-loader doesn't have documentation for using it outside of webpack (if that's even possible).

Is there a way to do this with rollup?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  plugins: [
      postcss({
        extract: true,
        minimize: true,
        use: [
          [
            'sass',
            {
              data: '@import "./variable.scss"; '
            }
          ]
        ]
      })
    ]
```

https://github.com/hytromo/rollup-plugin-postcss-retain-sass-data#readme

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).